# Support wildcards for tags in custom filter

Tags: feature-request, tags, custom-filter

I work mainly with Microsoft Azure and have set a custom filter with a number of `azure` related tags (e.g. `azure`, `azure-cosmosdb` etc.). This is how it looks on my laptop:

[image]

On mobile it gets worse as most of the screen is occupied with the tags I have set as part of the custom filter. The more tags I choose, the more real estate is gone displaying those tags.

Furthermore by choosing tags explicitly, I'm sure that I must have missed some tags related to Azure.

It would be incredibly fantastic if I can just **specify my custom filter as `azure*` and I can see all questions where the tag names associated with the questions start with `azure`**.

This will not only save the real estate on my browser + I will be sure not to miss out on any Azure related questions.

**UPDATE**

After posting the question, I reached out to someone who's also very active on Stack Overflow and he recommended me to explore the search functionality. To be very honest, I was not aware of the search capabilities so I gave that a try and here are my observations:

- Simply searching for `azure*` will search for `azure` in both questions and answers text which is not something I am looking for.
- Based on his recommendation, I did a tag search by using `[azure*]` and it does work to some extent. So when I do tag search with wildcard, it kind of explodes that and creates a search query like the following: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure+or+azure-devops+or+azure-active-directory+or+azure-functions+or+azure-web-app-service+or+azure-sql-database+or+azure-pipelines+or+azure-cosmosdb+or+azure-storage+or+azure-storage-blobs+or+azure-ad-b2c+or+azure-data-factory+or+azure-service-fabric+or+azure-application-insights+or+azureservicebus+or+azure-mobile-services+or+azure-logic-apps+or+azure-resource-manager+or+azure-table-storage+or+azure-webjobs`.

As you can see it simply finds the unique tags that start with `azure` and creates a URL that I can bookmark. This would work as long as no new azure related tags are added. If new tags are added, then I will have to redo the same process (and for that I have to be aware of the availability of the new tags).

Furthermore, I noticed that in the URL only a partial list of azure tags are added. For example, when I search for `azure` here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags, I can see 36 popular tags however the list included in the URL above is only 20. So obviously it is missing some relevant tags that are of interest to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use wildcards in the search URL directly, which will make it reactive to any new `azure*` tags that are created in the future:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure*

This won’t solve the large swath of tags appearing above the search results, but the URL stays succinct.

It still doesn't cover all the tags, but it's a start!

---

<del>This seems to cover all the azure tags I get back from the tag search; I only see [the 20 in your URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uAM1.jpg).</del>

So it turns out that I was wrong here; there are actually *212* `azure*` tags on Stack Overflow (you can see them all [using this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1382037/tag-search-with-wikis-and-excerpts?TagName=azure#resultSets), way too many to list here).

Unfortunately, trying to include them all [in a single URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-container-registry+or+azure-resource-graph+or+azure+or+azure-storage+or+azure-packaging+or+azure-pack+or+azure-cdn+or+azure-data-sync+or+azure-disk+or+azure-in-role-cache+or+azure-cloud-services+or+azure-service-fabric-mesh+or+azure-sentinel+or+azureshell+or+azure-vm-role+or+azure-compute-emulator+or+azure-traffic-manager+or+azure-sql-database+or+azure-analysis-services+or+azure-sdk-for-ruby+or+azure-container-instances+or+azure-managed-identity+or+azure-digital-twins+or+azure-aks+or+azure-monitoring+or+azure-pipelines-task-lib+or+azure-devops-server+or+azure-data-share+or+azure-rtos+or+azure-devops-migration-tools+or+azure-appfabric+or+azure-queues+or+azure-deployment+or+azure-marketplace+or+azure-virtual-machine+or+azure-zulu+or+azure-powershell+or+azure-storage-queues+or+azure-webjobssdk+or+azure-media-services+or+azure-android-sdk+or+sitecore-azure+or+azure-mobile-engagement+or+azure-api-apps+or+azure-service-fabric+or+sql-azure-federations+or+azure-data-lake+or+django-pyodbc-azure+or+azure-ad-b2c+or+azure-data-catalog+or+azure-vm-scale-set+or+azure-container-service+or+azure-language-understanding+or+azure-sdk-python+or+terraform-provider-azure+or+azure-machine-learning-workbench+or+azure-runbook+or+azure-iot-central+or+azure-maps+or+azure-application-proxy+or+azure-adf+or+azure-devops-artifacts+or+azure-storage-blobs+or+azure-web-roles+or+azure-diagnostics+or+azureservicebus+or+azure-acs+or+azure-clouddrive+or+azure-sdk-.net+or+azure-autoscaling-block+or+azure-active-directory+or+azure-webjobs+or+azure-machine-learning-studio+or+azure-eventhub+or+azure-xplat-cli+or+azure-cognitive-search+or+azure-virtual-network+or+azure-resource-manager+or+azure-application-insights+or+azure-elastic-scale+or+azure-app-service-envrmnt+or+azure-data-factory+or+azure-sqldw+or+azure-management-api+or+azure-keyvault+or+azure-servicebus-topics+or+azure-ad-graph-api+or+azure-batch+or+azure-redis-cache+or+azure-bot-service+or+azure-pipelines+or+azure-mcd+or+azure-database-mysql+or+azure-database-postgresql+or+azure-cloud-shell+or+azure-stack+or+azure-devtest-labs+or+azure-log-analytics+or+azure-timeseries-insights+or+azure-dsvm+or+azure-web-app-for-containers+or+azure-cli2+or+azure-billing-api+or+azure-oms+or+azure-backup-vault+or+azure-iot-edge+or+azure-postgresql+or+azure-china+or+azure-devops-rest-api+or+azure-data-explorer+or+azure-information-protection+or+azure-cosmosdb-tables+or+azure-repos+or+azure-data-studio+or+azure-ai+or+azure-load-balancer+or+azure-iot-dps+or+azure-waf+or+azure-speech+or+azure-pipeline-python-script-task+or+azure-sas+or+azure-monitor-workbooks+or+azure-eventhub-capture+or+azure-devops-services+or+azure-communication-services+or+azure-purview+or+azure-table-storage+or+azure-worker-roles+or+azure-sql-reporting+or+azure-java-sdk+or+azure-storage-emulator+or+azure-store+or+azure-servicebusrelay+or+azure-caching+or+azure-mobile-services+or+azure-1.8+or+azure-servicebus-queues+or+azure-scheduler+or+azure-affinity-group+or+azure-notificationhub+or+azure-api-management+or+azure-automation+or+azure-stream-analytics+or+azure-logic-apps+or+azure-devops+or+azure-iot-hub+or+azure-pipelines-build-task+or+azure-functions+or+azure-sdk+or+azure-iot-sdk+or+azureportal+or+azure-pipelines-release-pipeline+or+azure-cli+or+azure-ad-powershell-v2+or+azure-cosmosdb+or+azure-gov+or+azure-authentication+or+azure-ddos+or+azure-eventgrid+or+azure-rbac+or+azure-site-recovery+or+azure-security+or+azure-data-factory-2+or+azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi+or+azure-durable-functions+or+azure-triggers+or+azure-sphere+or+azure-mysql-database+or+azure-iot-hub-device-management+or+azure-artifacts+or+azure-webapps+or+azure-web-app-service+or+azure-nsg+or+azure-ad-b2b+or+azure-signalr+or+azure-lab-services+or+azure-function-async+or+azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api+or+azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi+or+azure-acr+or+azure-spatial-anchors+or+azure-blockchain-workbench+or+azure-databricks+or+azure-devops-server-2019+or+azure-boards+or+azure-dev-spaces+or+azure-machine-learning-service+or+azure-anomaly-detector+or+azure-app-configuration+or+azurekinect+or+azure-relay+or+azure-blockchain-service+or+azure-front-door+or+azure-sql-data-warehouse+or+azure-alerts+or+fhir-server-for-azure+or+azure-spring-cloud+or+azure-policy+or+azure-storage-explorer+or+azure-private-dns+or+azure-synapse+or+azure-data-lake-gen2+or+azure-devops-server-2020+or+azure-hdinsight+or+azure-rm+or+azure-bicep+or+azure-managed-app+or+azureml+or+azure-quantum+or+azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy+or+azure-ad-verifiable-credentials+or+azure-identity)... doesn't work very well (It's a 4596 character URL; Stack's apparent limit seems to be short of 2000, I think).

---

For some further investigation, I tried to put all 212 tags into a filter, but filters apparently have a hard limit of 99 tags (according to the error message I received):

[image: Please limit your query to 99 tags.]

This isn't even a limit applied by the UI that I could bypass either, since that message comes back in the server response to the web request made to create the filter:

> ```json
> {
>   "Success": false,
>   "Message": "Please limit your query to 99 tags.",
>   "ParametersId": 0
> }
> ```

---

After some *further*, further investigation, the error may *say* that 99's the limit, but trying to create a filter with 99 or 98 tags still sends the message. I found the actual limit to be 50 tags in practice.

**Final findings:**

- A tag search for `azure*` will actually search for the *top 20* most popular tags (highest question count) that match that wildcard

  - An `azure*` *filter* does the same
- When specifically using `+` characters in the URL (or the equivalent HTML escape, `%2b`) instead of spaces (either   or `%20`), you can search for at least the top 99 tags if you use `azure*` to cover the top 20

  - [Top 99 `azure*` tags question search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure*%2bor%2bazure-powershell%2bor%2bazure-virtual-machine%2bor%2bazure-data-factory-2%2bor%2bazure-aks%2bor%2bazure-keyvault%2bor%2bazure-databricks%2bor%2bazure-api-management%2bor%2bazure-iot-hub%2bor%2bazure-ad-graph-api%2bor%2bazure-data-lake%2bor%2bazure-pipelines-release-pipeline%2bor%2bazure-eventhub%2bor%2bazure-devops-rest-api%2bor%2bazure-language-understanding%2bor%2bazure-cognitive-search%2bor%2bazure-cli%2bor%2bazure-web-roles%2bor%2bazure-cloud-services%2bor%2bterraform-provider-azure%2bor%2bazure-hdinsight%2bor%2bazure-virtual-network%2bor%2bazure-pipelines-build-task%2bor%2bazure-data-explorer%2bor%2bazure-worker-roles%2bor%2bazure-stream-analytics%2bor%2bazure-servicebus-queues%2bor%2bazure-bot-service%2bor%2bazure-machine-learning-studio%2bor%2bazure-notificationhub%2bor%2bazure-media-services%2bor%2bazure-log-analytics%2bor%2bazure-automation%2bor%2bazureportal%2bor%2bazure-iot-edge%2bor%2bazure-synapse%2bor%2bazure-servicebus-topics%2bor%2bazure-monitoring%2bor%2bazure-machine-learning-service%2bor%2bazure-webjobssdk%2bor%2bazure-deployment%2bor%2bazure-sdk-.net%2bor%2bazure-container-instances%2bor%2bazure-artifacts%2bor%2bazure-cdn%2bor%2bazure-sqldw%2bor%2bazure-container-service%2bor%2bazure-api-apps%2bor%2bazure-managed-identity%2bor%2bazure-durable-functions%2bor%2bazure-eventgrid%2bor%2bazure-ad-b2c-custom-policy%2bor%2bazure-queues%2bor%2bazure-diagnostics%2bor%2bazure-batch%2bor%2bazure-webapps%2bor%2bazure-app-service-envrmnt%2bor%2bazure-vm-scale-set%2bor%2bazure-container-registry%2bor%2bazure-cosmosdb-mongoapi%2bor%2bazure-devops-server-2019%2bor%2bazure-analysis-services%2bor%2bazure-authentication%2bor%2bazure-storage-queues%2bor%2bazure-iot-sdk%2bor%2bazure-redis-cache%2bor%2bazure-data-lake-gen2%2bor%2bazure-load-balancer%2bor%2bazure-sdk%2bor%2bazure-policy%2bor%2bazure-runbook%2bor%2bazure-sdk-python%2bor%2bazure-traffic-manager%2bor%2bazure-repos%2bor%2bazure-java-sdk%2bor%2bazure-caching%2bor%2bazure-maps%2bor%2bazure-sql-data-warehouse%2bor%2bazure-boards%2bor%2bazure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi)
- In practice, the filter tag quantity limit seems to be exactly *50* written tags

  - You can seemingly cheese this with wildcard tags, as `azure*` appears to count as only one tag
  - [Largest savable filter of `azure*` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure*+or+azure-devops+or+azure-active-directory+or+azure-functions+or+azure-web-app-service+or+azure-sql-database+or+azure-pipelines+or+azure-cosmosdb+or+azure-storage+or+azure-storage-blobs+or+azure-ad-b2c+or+azure-data-factory+or+azure-service-fabric+or+azure-application-insights+or+azureservicebus+or+azure-mobile-services+or+azure-logic-apps+or+azure-resource-manager+or+azure-table-storage+or+azure-webjobs+or+azure-powershell+or+azure-virtual-machine+or+azure-data-factory-2+or+azure-aks+or+azure-keyvault+or+azure-databricks+or+azure-api-management+or+azure-iot-hub+or+azure-ad-graph-api+or+azure-data-lake+or+azure-pipelines-release-pipeline+or+azure-eventhub+or+azure-devops-rest-api+or+azure-language-understanding+or+azure-cognitive-search+or+azure-cli+or+azure-web-roles+or+azure-cloud-services+or+terraform-provider-azure+or+azure-hdinsight+or+azure-virtual-network+or+azure-pipelines-build-task+or+azure-data-explorer+or+azure-worker-roles+or+azure-stream-analytics+or+azure-servicebus-queues+or+azure-bot-service+or+azure-machine-learning-studio+or+azure-notificationhub+or+azure-media-services?sort=Newest&uqlId=44374) (top 69 tags, 49 normal + 20 from wildcard)

Comment: Expanding on this you can also save `azure*` in *watched tags* UI which results in same url link

Comment: Thanks! Doing `azure*` still does not bring all Azure related tags (e.g. `azure-storage-queues`).